# Installed PHP 5.4 via OS X binary, but `php` in terminal still uses 5.3

Tags: php, bash, terminal, osx-lion

I used a nice one-line command to install PHP 5.4 Mac OS X Lion, from [php-osx.liip.ch](http://php-osx.liip.ch/). This is working perfectly in Apache – my local sites are now using PHP 5.4.

But when I run `php -v` from the terminal, it still uses version 5.3. This is causing problems.

`which php` gives me `/usr/bin/php`, so that's where the old version is still installed. And after some digging I've found that the 5.4 binary is located at `/usr/local/php5/bin/php`.

So I'm nearly there... But how do I make the `php` command resolve to `/usr/local/php5/bin/php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the old copy of the file, you can just remove it and create a symbolic link to `/usr/local/php5/bin/php`. You can use `ln -s` command. This will be easier than playing with your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I didn't delete `/usr/bin/php`, I just renamed it to `php_OLD` just in case...

Comment: @callum: That's better :)

Comment: @Khaled I am also having the same issue. I followed your answer and now It does show new version with php -v command but using phpinfo() function shows older version. Could you please look at my [post](http://serverfault.com/questions/472768/installed-new-version-of-php-but-server-still-uses-older-version)